# PROBLEMA CONEXION SSH DE VISUAL CODE A LINUX

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox

Decidí instalar el visual studio code en mi maquina Windows y crear una maquina virtual remota Linux.

Para ahorrar recursos decidí hacer un ssh desde mi maquina principal a la virtual.

Ya instale todo pero no me deja hacer ssh.

Realice los siguientes comandos en mi linux

```
$ sudo apt install ssh
$ sudo apt install openssh-client
```

Y corre todo normal. El problema es en la conexion con el vstudio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo configuraste la red en VirtualBox? ¿Cuál distribución de Linux?

Comment: @Sal la red aumente una nueva en la parte de nombre le puse sssh , puerto anfitrion 2223 y puerto invitado 22. Ya en el visual studiocode al poner en la conf. coloque Host stefhanie (nombre que quiero para el host) HostName 127.0.0.1 User (mi nombre de usuario) Port 2223 y ya y sigue sin conectar :( estoy usando ubuntu

Comment: Me refiero a la [configuración de la red](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-network) de la [VM](https://www.opentechguides.com/images/howto/howto_14001.png).

Comment: ¿Estas segura de que tu servidor ssh en ubuntu esta corriendo?, asegurate que este funcionando ejecuta: `systemctl status sshd` y cuéntanos que te sale.